# Apache HTTP VM Behind HTTPS Lets Encrypt

Tags: apache, ssl, proxypass

I've read a lot of questions and answers which seem exactly the same as mine, but I can't seem to get my setup to work.  I have a VM running Apache with only HTTP support at `192.168.2.101:32773`.  I can access it on my local network as such just fine.  I now am ready to expose it through my Apache web server that has Lets Encrypt setup to generate SSL certificates.  So I added this to my server conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:32773>
    ServerName server.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.com/privkey.pem

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.2.101:32773/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.2.101:32773/
</VirtualHost>
```

However, I get an `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` when I try to load it up as `https://server.com:32773`.  If I however change my address to `http://server.com:32773`, it loads just fine.  Anything look wrong in this snippet?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarrassing...  At some point I changed my port forward rules to point `32773` directly to `192.168.2.101` so I could validate that the rules were working at all.  The above config worked as soon as I realized I wasn't even sending traffic to my Apache SSL enabled server.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP and HTTPS need to be on different ports. Typically HTTPS is served on port 443.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.  My main Apache webserver (where this conf file is from), is not 192.168.2.101.  That's a separate physical device.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your configuration.One odd thing in the snippet, but perhaps just a typo: in the `SSLCertificateKeyFile` path, should `server` be `server.com`?

Comment: Yes, just a typo in the posting.  I'll correct that.  Thanks for noticing.